Как перевести в верхний регистр подстроку в строке?

Дана некоторая строка
'a bc def ghij'
Переведите в верхний регистр все подстроки, в которых количество букв меньше или равно трем. В нашем случае должно получится следующее:
'A BC DEF ghij'

Подскажите варианты решения.

Вам же на подобный вопрос подробно отвечали - вот и используйте приобретённые знания.

Вы упомянули "подстроки", не "слова". Тогда правильное решение - поднять регистр все строке от начала до конца. Если вы имели ввиду слова, тогда в задаче больше смысла.

а у вас какие варианты решения?

Строку можно разрезать по границам слов:
import re

print(''.join(t if len(t) > 3 else t.upper() for t in re.split('\\b', input())))


Режем, перебираем, преобразуем, склеиваем обратно
print(' '.join(w.upper() if len(w) < 4 else w for w in 'a bc def ghij'.split()))

A BC DEF ghij


split() -> split(' '). Имеет смысл, если вы хотите сохранить все пробелы на их местах.

Простая задачка, хоть и решил я ее через одно место:
stroka = 'sdfsdf sd ff adsfsd'
stroka = stroka.split(" ")
s = ""
for i in stroka:
    if len(i) <=3:
        s += i.upper()+" "
    else:
        s += i + " "
print(s[:-1])


У вас в строчке на выходе будет лишний пробел в конце

Я знаю, но если это принципиально, то я его сейчас уберу

Идея хорошая, но теперь если пустую строчку в алгоритм податите, то IndexError получите :)

Поэтому не подадим) Ерорры всем решениям выбит. А вообще тогда перед циклом надо дать условие, которое проверит общую длину строки, и пошлет в пешее эротическое обладателя пробела или пустой строки)

Всё намного проще

Да те же яйца, только вычислений больше, а так - просто последний символ от строки откинули... Плюс - плюс одна переменная. У людей, у которых в строчку прикольнее и быстро действеннее, чем у нас

@dofi4ka, ошибки не будет. Конструкция s[:-1] работает на пустой строке. А вот s[-1] сломалась бы, но тут её нет.

@Stanislav Volodarskiy скорее всего она имела ввиду, что при попытке сплитовать пустую строку на пробелы ошибка выскочит

@StanislavVolodarskiy да я забыл немного, срезы IndexError не вызывают
